# pyftdi finds device under OS X but not Windows

Tags: windows-7, libusb

I have an FTDI FT230XS plugged into my MacBook Pro.  The following works under OS X / python3.6:

```
from pyftdi.ftdi import Ftdi
x = Ftdi()
x.open_bitbang_from_url('ftdi:///1')
```

However, I'm having trouble doing the same thing under VirtualBox running Windows 7 (32 bit).  I've taken pains to make sure the USB device is present in the VirtualBox environment: I get the little "bu-dum!" sound when I plug it in, and `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` confirms that it is present.  However, the open fails:

```
>>> from pyftdi.ftdi import Ftdi
>>> x = Ftdi()
>>> x.open_bitbang_from_url('ftdi:///1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...site-packages\pyftdi\usbtools.py", line 375, in parse_url
    candidates[idx]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
pyftdi.usbtools.UsbToolsError: No USB device matches URL ftdi:///1
```

Any idea of what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already loaded libusb-win32 from some source (Zadig, libusb win32, etc), you need to declare the FTDI device to Windows as [described in the documentation](http://eblot.github.io/pyftdi/installation.html#windows).  A recap of the steps:

- download and install `libusb-win32-devel-filter-x.x.x.x.exe` from the [libusb-win32 Sourceforge site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/).  Choose the latest release (currently 1.2.6.0) and make sure you download the `devel-filter` installer.
- Plug in your FTDI device, click to run the installer and follow the directions.  It should create a filter for your specific device.

Comment: It would be better if you write your questions as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Emmanuel: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for the awesome pyftdi library!  I just went back and installed libusb win32 v 1.2.6.0 using Zadig (thanks for the tip!).  But I couldn't figure out how to create the "filter": I don't see any directory named LibUSB-Win32 anywhere on C:.

Comment: I realized my error: I didn't notice the libusb-win32-devel-FILTER installer.  Once I did that, it all worked.  I went back and fleshed out Emmanuel's answer to reflect the steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to download [ZADIG](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) and use it to install libusb for the device you want to use in pyusb.

Remember to flag "Show all devices" in the Options menu.

[image: Zadig]

[image: Result]

Comment: This is the easiest solution as suggested in the documentation for pyftdi. You will need to run Zadig with administration privileges.